# Replace object value into an Array

Tags: php

Hello i'm trying to replace an object value into array in php but I can't access to the object while using foreach or other php method.

Here is the array and I would like to go inside the WP_Term object to change the taxonomy value

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'text' => 'Accueil',
    'url' => 'http://docker.localhost:8004',
    'allow_html' => true,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'term' => 
    WP_Term::__set_state(array(
       'term_id' => 113,
       'name' => 'Animation séminaire',
       'slug' => 'animation-seminaire',
       'term_group' => 0,
       'term_taxonomy_id' => 113,
       'taxonomy' => 'decouvrir',
       'description' => '',
       'parent' => 0,
       'count' => 123,
       'filter' => 'raw',
    )),
    10715 => 
    array (
      'taxonomy' => 'test',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'id' => 396,
  ),
)
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by getting the array key in a variable and then assign the property:

```
$term = $array[1]['term']; # get the obj in arr
$term->taxonomy = 'foo'; # set obj property

echo '<pre>'. print_r($array, 1) .'</pre>'; # print arr - will show updated val
```